# What is this input type or form setup called?

Tags: forms, input, html5

Couple of us arguing about this and none of us can remember what this is or would be called. Commonly seen on forms where you are moving an option from one box on the left to a box on the right and commonly has buttons in between the two boxes to move a singular option or all options. Crude visual example below (since we can't remember it enough to search for an actual example).

```
------------         -------------------
| Option 1 |         | Selected Option |
| Option 2 |   ->    |                 |
| Option 3 |   -->   |                 |
| Option 4 |   <-    |                 |
| Option 5 |   <--   |                 |
| Option 6 |         |                 |
------------         -------------------
```

What would this be called?

...and, no, you don't have to tell me how mind-blowingly and award winning my illustration is. I am aware. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Picklist

While these particular elements are often referred to as "Multi-select menus" that term is ambiguous because it is just as commonly used to refer to standard select menus where you can select multiple options using checkboxes.

Picklist, on the other hand, I have only seen used to refer to this type of element. Here are a few references

**Jquery Picklist**

> Turns an HTML multiple option select box into a side-by-side pick list control
> https://plugins.jquery.com/picklist/

**PrimeFace Picklist**

> PickList is a dual list input component
> http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml

**Javascript Kit Picklist**

> PickList creates two form selection fields, and allows the user to easily transfer items from one field to another via "back" and "forth" buttons.
> http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/picklist.shtml

Answer (score 1):

**Select Columns**

Our team always calls that a "select columns" dialog.

When I search in Google Images, it seems to be pretty widely recognized that way:

https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=select+columns+dialog